# Crear una funcion que me pase una lista con int, a una lista con str

Tags: python, lista, funciones

Esto buscando crear una función que me pase una lista de números:

```
SA = [6704430, 9219120, 6732330, 6932190, 6732340]
```

A una lista con strings, de esta forma:

```
SA = ["6704430", "9219120", "6732330", "6932190", "6732340"]
```

¿Me podrían dar una ayuda?

Comment: segun tu pregunta anterior, ya arregle eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo tienes que pasarle `str()` a cada elemento:

```
   SA = [6704430, 9219120, 6732330, 6932190, 6732340]
    
    print([str(n) for n in SA])
    
    # Devuelve: ['6704430', '9219120', '6732330', '6932190', '6732340']
```